# nginx proxy pass depending on requested file

Tags: nginx

Hello I am new to Nginx and I can't seem to find any proper resources to help me out.

My code

```
location / {
set $foobar http://test.com;
if ($request_uri = "test") {
    set $foobar http://example.com;
    return 200 $foobar;
    break;
}
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass $foobar;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

What I am trying to do as you might have deduced is that if the url is `http://mydomain.ca/test` to show `http://example.com` and if not then default to `http://test.com`.

However, I might have first of all gotten some syntax wrong because all I get is error 502.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your configuration file, and there is no need to use `if` and `set`. The following may be better:

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_redirect off;

   location /test/ {
      proxy_pass http://test.com;
   }

   proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

However, the *502 Bad Gateway* error usually means that your server cannot find the remote server, perhaps due to a DNS, routing, firewall or port problem.

Comment: But do you have any place I could read about `if`, `set` and variables in general?

Comment: @cosayoxum Useful resources are: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ and https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/

Comment: @cosayoxum And if you haven't done so already, read: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ and https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: I tried to read those but the pages won't load.. Is this isolated to just me?